# Bash script to retrieve name of Ethernet Network interface

Tags: ubuntu, networking, bash, linux-networking, scripting

In Ubuntu 16.04 I made a script to dinamically configure IP address of the wired ethernet interface based on certain parameters.
Now the problem is that in my script I assume that the name is eth0, but this is not always true.. assuming that I have only one wired network interface (not necessary plugged) but I can have also a wireless interface, how can I retrieve its name (just the wired one)?

with `ifconfig` command I get:

```
enp7s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fc:3f:db:a2:6d:46  
          inet addr:192.168.0.101  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::149f:3103:af2f:1ec5/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:6784 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7493 errors:1 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:4565079 (4.5 MB)  TX bytes:827825 (827.8 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:8037 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8037 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:2261250 (2.2 MB)  TX bytes:2261250 (2.2 MB)

wlp19s0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c8:ff:28:93:26:32  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:180463 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:121275 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:229823414 (229.8 MB)  TX bytes:15675806 (15.6 MB)
```

What I want is:

```
enp7s0
```

Comment: I think you want something like `ip link | awk -F: '$0 !~ "lo|vir|^[^0-9]"{print $2a;getline}'`

Comment: this will show also the wireless adapter

Comment: #rok, it does but aren't you mentioning it in your question as well?  `but I can have also a wireless interface, how can I retrieve its name`

Comment: edited with details, please see

Comment: Ok then this will fix it: `ip link | awk -F: '$0 !~ "lo|vir|wl|^[^0-9]"{print $2a;getline}'`

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for! post it as answer...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to exclude interfaces like `vir` , `loopback` and `wl`(wireless) then the following should do the trick.

```
ip link | awk -F: '$0 !~ "lo|vir|wl|^[^0-9]"{print $2;getline}'
```

Here we use colon as delimiter `-F:` then check if the row `$0` does not match a certain string using regular expression.

**Update:**
Using the `-brief` flag as suggested in the comment, the command changes to:

```
ip -br l | awk '$1 !~ "lo|vir|wl" { print $1}'
```

Comment: Don't forget `tun` for future readers.

Comment: Instead of complicated `awk`, use `-brief` flag of `ip` command: `ip -br l | cut -d\  -f1` ... Then you could `| grep -v '^w\|^lo$' ...`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. But now you are introducing 2 processes `cut` and `grep`. The filtering still needs to happen.

Comment: Don't forget `ppp`, `vcan`, `can`, `docker`, `br` and countless other examples that are not Ethernet. In other words, this method is crapshoot.

Comment: To select ethernet only is it possible to use the fact `ifconfig` contains `mtu 1500` for ethernet?

Comment: `ifconfig` is deprecated so you should not use it. Instead use `ip` and something like `ip a sh <interface_name> | grep -wo 'mtu [0-9]\+'` to spit out the mtu size.

Answer (score 17):

Because all interfaces would displayed under `/sys/class/`, such as `/sys/class/net/` listing all network interfaces,

it is possible to directly use this directly search and return the exact interface name through a simple keyword like:

`ls /sys/class/net | grep enp`

Comment: If you want to include interfaces like "eth0" as well, change the grep from `enp` to `^e` and it will match both eth* and enp*

Answer (score 7):

Here is best solution

> ip route get 8.8.8.8 | awk -- '{printf $5}'

or

> echo $(ip route get 8.8.8.8 | awk -- '{printf $5}')

in bash script you can declare main_interface and use anywhere as $main_interface

> main_interface=$(ip route get 8.8.8.8 | awk -- '{printf $5}')

Comment: As it stands, means a trip out to a google site but I like it as a way of finding which interface is actually being used to reach the web or a particular site.

Comment: Sorry, I have to muddle my comment just made above. I don't actually know that a trip was made to the site. I'm seeing the same valid results even when I enter an address I know not to exist. So seems like a good way to see which interface the routing table is setup to use.

Comment: This is a great simple way to check which interface is connected to your default gateway. Not sure why this isn't the top answer.

Answer (score 4):

I'd use `ifconfig`(bit old and deprecated) tool or `ip` command. Using `ip route` you are having a list of available routes. Then get only line containing ***default*** with `grep` and strip the unwanted characters off the string using `sed`

full command goes like:

`ip route | grep default | sed -e "s/^.*dev.//" -e "s/.proto.*//"`

Comment: It's only working if the ethernet port is connected, otherwise could also show the wireless adapter name if connected to a wifi network...

Comment: @rok don't you need the default interface always regardless of Ethernet or wireless?

Comment: No.. I just need the Ethernet name

Comment: This would have been my answer.  @rok your question sounds like you want the interface whether it is wired or wireless.  Please edit your question to clarify.

Answer (score 3):

The trick is to get the list of interfaces from `/sys/class/net` and then look where they go to.

```
find /sys/class/net ! -type d | xargs --max-args=1 realpath | awk -F\/ '/pci/{print $NF}'
```

To filter on Ethernet only, you would have to grep `lspci` first:

```
lspci  | awk '/Ethernet/{print $1}'
```

The complete command becomes:

```
pci=`lspci  | \
 awk '/Ethernet/{print $1}'`; find /sys/class/net ! -type d  | \
 xargs --max-args=1 realpath  | \
 awk -v pciid=$pci -F\/ '{if($0 ~ pciid){print $NF}}'
```

Comment: no.. I also have a wireless interface

Comment: @rok Try the last command. Wireless interface won't show up as "Ethernet". That's the whole point of this solution. However, this solution won't work with USB Ethernet dongles.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by the answer from @千木郷, but not wanting to invoke any external processes, I'd use this:

```
$(basename /sys/class/net/en*)
```

That will return an error if there are multiple devices starting with `en`, but if you want them all you can add a `-a` to the basename command.

For wireless devices, use the prefix `wl` instead of `en`. The naming scheme [rationale](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/) and the [reference code for `builtin_net_id()](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/main/src/udev/udev-builtin-net_id.c#L842) provide more help.

Answer (score 0):

Most ethernet interfaces start with `e` (`eth` or `en`) so you can just filter on that....

```bash
IFACE_NAME=$(ip --brief link | awk '{print $1}' | grep -E '^e.*' | tr -d '\n')
echo $IFACE_NAME
IFACE_ADDR=$(ip -4 --brief addr show dev $IFACE_NAME | awk '{print $3}' | cut -d'/' -f1 | tr -d '\n')
echo $IFACE_ADDR
```

If you want to be more robust you can do a `wc -l` to make sure you have 1 and only 1 matching interface name.

To be more deterministic you can parse files in `/etc/sysconfig/network` (redhat/centos) or `/etc/network/interfaces` or `/etc/netplan/` etc to find interface names by type.